# GoFlex Home drive visible but won't mount

Tags: mount, networking, nas

How do I get the "GoFlex Home" network drive to mount in ubuntu 10.4?

Answer (score 2):

On my 11.10 install, the nautilus file browser is able to find it automatically, and calls it an "AFP volume".  See  [Fstab for GoFlex Home 2tb NAS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22559/fstab-for-goflex-home-2tb-nas/95731#95731)

I think it is possible to add AFP functionality to Ubuntu since 9.04, according to  http://missingreadme.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/how-to-set-up-afp-filesharing-on-ubuntu/  ... Hope that helps

PS   I should add:  you can access the GoFlex configuration page using a web browser, by typing in the ip address for the drive as your web location.  This information might be under "attached devices" in your router page, which often times is a very similar process.  *For example:  If you see 192.168.0.4 as your Ubuntu machine's IP address (type 'ifconfig' in the terminal), then your router is probably 192.168.0.1, and your GoFlex is probably 192.168.0.5 or something.*

Answer (score 0):

Run `fsck <drive name>` to see whether or not the filesystem is in good shape (no errors, bad sectors, etc.).  Then try again.